# Is a good pratice to use inheritance to divide methods?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I got a long class (600 lines) and deciding to refactor all these nasty code.
So I thinking about dividing the methods into multiple class:

```py
    class Uploader:
        def print(self):
            print(self.a)

        def upload(self):
            ...
        ...

    class Indexer:
        def load_index(self):
            ...
        ...

    class JsonManager(Indexer):
        def save_chunk(self):
            ...
        ...
    class MainObject(Uploader, JsonManager):
        def __init__(self, a):
            self.a = a
            ...
```

one issue is that methods will use instance attribute of MainObject that is not defined in parents (Eg. print method in Uploader, a is not defined in Uploader but in MainObject).
Is this a good practice or an another way exists ?

Comment: 600 lines is fine, just chill. In my experience inheritance rarely makes things seem any tider. Unless you're building a framework for someone else to use its not worth the bother. You might be able to refactor into different objects that are passed in via dependency injection, that can help untangle things sometimes. But sometimes it can make it worse. Good luck

Comment: _"methods will use instance attribute of MainObject that is not defined in parents"_ sounds like an anti-pattern

Comment: it would be safer if you define function `print()` in `Uploader` which raises error [NotImplementedError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError) and iformation that this function has to be defined in child class

Comment: @Anentropic I could make an __init__ method which set this attribute and call super init with this attribute to make it sound less anti-pattern I think

Comment: @furas the purpose of my parent class is to reduce the size of the leaf class, it would be safer but I need to define my function in Uploader (one way to be safer is to look if my attribute has been set but seems dirty and repetitive, the other way is to do what I wrote in my comment above)

Comment: my safer method is standard method to do it in clean way. `Upload` defines function `print()` with `NotImplementedError` and later `MainObject` replace it with own function `print()`. If you forgot to define `print()` in `MainObject` then error `NotImplementedError` inform you that you have to define own `print()` in own class. And if you want to reduce size then keep all in `MainObject` as before

Comment: eventually `Upload` shouldn't use `print()` in its code but only return value - and `MainObject` should get value `result = upload()` and use it with own function `print(result)`. And if you really have to use `print` inside `upload` then you can send it as parameter (`callback`) - `def upload(..., callback=None)` and `upload` can use `if  callback: callback()`, and later run it as `upload( ..., callback=print)`